# List of IP address for a host

Tags: dns

We could see multiple ip addresses for a single host like facebook, google etc.
My question is why a host maintains so many ip addresses ? what is the purpose for it? Does it wont overlap with any other Public addresses.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose is to distribuite the work load on different datacenter on different geographical areas. They use a single domain name (like facebook.com) to hide a big network of datacenter ready to reply to requests. The real host to which you will be connected is decided dynamically based on your position and the load of the different datacenter.